# PHP prevent back button cached resubmission without javascript

Tags: php, forms, back

I have a form where the user types in data and submits it to itself. In my code, I process this data and then do a redirect to itself again to prevent refresh re-submissions (I don't use PRG because the URL can be bookmarked).

simple example (index.php):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submitted"])) {
    // do data processing

    header("location:index.php?success=1");
    die();
}
?>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <p><input type="text" name="foo"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submitted"></p>
</form>
```

Unlike questions such as this ([Prevent Form resubmission upon hitting back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226744/prevent-form-resubmission-upon-hitting-back-button)), my problem is not that pressing the back button asks me to re-submit. My problem is that when I press back, the browser (specifically chrome) has cached the inputs and displays them. Because of this, the user can click the submit button once again to spam my site/make duplicates.

I looked at questions such as this ([Prevent back button exploits? PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962682/prevent-back-button-exploits-php)) but I don't want to set a time limit, and unique identifiers don't work because the values are pasted in by php (hidden input doesn't retain value because it's pasted in and php generates a new token for each visit (including back)).

I could probably use AJAX to solve this problem ([Preventing form resubmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923904/preventing-form-resubmission)), but I can't think of a way to "gracefully degrade" if javascript is disabled ("you can't submit because you don't have javascript enabled, sorry" :D).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @developerwjk When protecting from malicious intent, you can't rely on "browsers" to respect headers

Answer (score 2):

Set no-cache headers on the form page:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submitted"])) 
{
    // do data processing
    header("Location: index.php?success=1");
    die();
}
else
{
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
}
?>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <p><input type="text" name="foo"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submitted"></p>
</form>
```

Now the form with the values filled out will not be cached. Going back to the form will result in having to refresh the form page, which should bring it up with the values empty.

Answer (score 0):

If resubmitting when user go back is your main problem, then following PRG pattern is good for you. But be sure you don't mix the page for view and submit handler. Mixing this is bad idea, against the Single Responsibility Principle rule. I don't think the URL can be bookmarked will be a problem when you follow PRG pattern, unless you still show something to the user on the post handler (f.e displaying success message), then you actually don't follow the PRG pattern.

But if you still enjoy mixing them both, the @developerwjk should solve the problem. Another approach, you can create unique token for each post (via hidden input). And then the post handler should check whether this token has been submitted by someone else or not. Put the unique token in the session is good, so you can check it later. Make sure you set the session expirity. This should not cause submitting duplicate data again.